# Docker cant find library Golang

Tags: docker, go

Docker can`t build my package. It cant find "language.Builder" library. Although it is official library.

Docker error message:

```
Step 4/6 : RUN go build ./cmd/metrics_aggregator.go
 ---> Running in 9fdcba6f9305
# golang.org/x/text/internal/language/compact
vendor/golang.org/x/text/internal/language/compact/language.go:176:7: undefined: language.Builder
vendor/golang.org/x/text/internal/language/compact/language.go:207:14: undefined: language.Builder
Error response from daemon: The command '/bin/sh -c go build ./cmd/metrics_aggregator.go' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

This is my docker file:

```
FROM golang:1.14 AS builder
WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY . .
RUN go build ./cmd/metrics_aggregator.go
```

My go.mod requirements:

```
require (
    github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go v3.2.0+incompatible
    github.com/google/uuid v1.1.2
    github.com/lib/pq v1.4.0 // indirect
    github.com/nats-io/nats.go v1.11.0
    gitlab.maiv.biz/exprowhite/env v0.0.7
    golang.org/x/oauth2 v0.0.0-20210628180205-a41e5a781914
    google.golang.org/api v0.49.0
    gorm.io/driver/postgres v1.1.0
    gorm.io/gorm v1.21.11
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a proxy server? If you are, you should configure Docker to use a proxy server. Here is a sample screenshot from my Docker Desktop.

[image: Docker desktop proxy settings]

Also, besides Docker, what is the output of this command

```
go get golang.org/x/text/internal/language/compact
```

It should provide more detailed information about the error.

Comment: Out put is: 
`C:\Users\igtat\go\src\google-analytics>go get golang.org/x/text/internal/language/compact
go: found golang.org/x/text/internal/language/compact in golang.org/x/text v0.3.6
`
No, I am not using proxy

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue while using Docker and it was because I had a `.dockerignore` entry for `**/compose*`. It turns out, the typedef for `language.Builder` lived in a file called `compose.go` and so it didn't get included in the build context! Once I changed that to `**/compose.y*ml` it built just fine.